# Why I'm receiving this error in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, xampp, timezone, firebase-authentication

I'm using `kreatit firebase php sdk`. But now I'm receiving this error in laravel during `idToken validation`.

```
 This token has been issued in the future at 2018-07-27T05:43:55+00:00, is your system time correct?
```

I have already changed the timezone in `php.ini`, `my.ini`, and also in laravel `config/app.php`.
But still, I'm receiving this error. Also, the idToken is verified only for the first time and after that, it shows the above error.

Comment: I thinks it's not related to server timezone, it's related to server time itself,
as it says token time is a time in future,
check your server time.

Comment: my server is local xampp server. And I have already changed the timezone.